# Symfony exception when running composer update

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, laravel-9

I get the following after running `composer update`, which invokes this artisan command:

```
> @php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force
PHP Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException:  The "--tag" option does not exist. in /var/www/integratielayer/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 217
```

Here's the full stacktrace: https://hastebin.com/share/viwatajaku.ruby

I encounter the same thing with other artisan commands too, for example:

```
>  php artisan queue:work --timeout=5000
PHP Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException:  The "--timeout" option does not exist.
```

Full stacktrace: https://hastebin.com/share/efidocujiw.ruby

I'm on Composer 2.5.4, PHP 8.2.3 and Laravel 9.52.
Looks like an issue between Laravel and Symfony, and I don't know how to go about fixing it.
I tried removing `composer.lock` and reinstalling my dependencies, no success. Also tried downgrading Laravel to 9.0.0.